# IN android studio i try to run simple hello world program

Tags: android

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.0/appcompat-v7-22.1.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.0/appcompat-v7-22.1.0.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/sivaram/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.0/appcompat-v7-22.1.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/sivaram/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.0/appcompat-v7-22.1.0.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/sivaram/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.0/appcompat-v7-22.1.0.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/sivaram/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.0/appcompat-v7-22.1.0.jar
>        Required by:
>            Firstone:app:unspecified

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've already download the android studio sdk, available here:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

If you already download try to install in the SDK manager the support library.

Hope it help you.